# Code-only answers

Tags: discussion, answers, low-quality-posts, code-only-answers

Does Stackoverflow follow this principle?

- [Is there any benefit to allowing code-only answers while blocking code-only questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques)

I found a user that only dump code (with the text "You can use this code"), so I wrote a comment telling, "for an answer to be useful, it needs an explanation, what doesn't work, what they did and why/how that works".

They kept answering with a code dump + "use this code", and after looking at a random amount (20-25) among their last 60, **all** were the same.

---

According to [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310219/are-answers-that-contain-only-commented-code-acceptable), one shouldn't flag the user, though I did, as they simply didn't care about my comments, or downvotes (can't do too many, or else they will look like "revenge downvote", and backfire on me).

*Also one more user commented and told them to provide some explanation, hence the "We've" in below quote*

Wrote this when flagged for moderator:

> We've told this user to post more that "try this" + code dump, but no
>   reaction. They also seems to have a preset code base in a lot of their
>   answers, linking jQuery etc., whether it is needed or not, and I find
>   that a really bad way to post answers

Got this answer:

> declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of
>   content that requires their intervention

---

So my question is simply, should we allow a user to just keep going with this type of answering, and if not, if moderator decline such flagging, to whom should we flag?

*I noticed that other users start doing the same (at the same questions), so I really believe, if this user is allowed to go on, other will do the same.*

---

Regarding if this is a duplicate, this question is somewhat (IMO) different to this, [try-this-code-answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256359/flag-try-this-code-answers-as-very-low-quality), as I don't ask if we should flag code-dump-only/low-quality-answer, I ask if a user making it their answering pattern, should be allowed to continue with no other than a once-in-a-while downvote/comment.

Comment: don't flag at all. If you find the post needs a little clarification, feel free to edit it. if you don't want to edit it, feel free to downvote it or leave a comment stating your objection -- but an answer with code only isn't something that is flaggable.

Comment: Welcome to where SO is headed

Comment: If you worry about looking like a "revenge downvoter," then just downvote such answers when you come across them "naturally" while browsing questions, don't go through the user's answers and vote.

Comment: @KevinB Am afraid it is...disappointing.

Comment: @JeanneDark Not worried in itself, more disappointed to not get response for it.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker So we just let a user post 82 answers (and still counting) like that...?

Comment: Not all code-only answers are bad answers. It is situational. Bad answers deserve to be downvoted, not flagged.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I know that...and if you looked at them, you would understand. Several were actually wrong (not solving the question), which again shouldn't be flagged, still being an answer. What I ask here is, "Should we just allow users to, IMHO, pollute SO like that, given it is a pattern?"

Comment: If their answers are consistently low-quality and consistently downvoted, wouldn't they eventually get answer-banned anyway? You could certainly make the argument that they should have tripped the answer ban already...

Comment: @F1Krazy Obviously not, as they still keep going...hence me posting here

Comment: @F1Krazy Don't forget the might of "pity upvotes". It is not rare for bad posts to get (at least) one upvote, because the poor fellow just wanted to help. And a single upvote can "undo" 5 downvotes, when looking at reputation.

Comment: I am very bad at writing in English, so quite often I leave code-only answers. I'd love to make a good description, but I just can't. There are thousands of non-native English users that's why they make such answers. Remove them all - stackoverflow will be empty.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov I can't speak for LGSon, but I'm not looking for crystal clear English; just an attempt at explaining what the problem was and how the code presented fixes that problem. Bad English can be fixed -- no English cannot.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov -- No, it won't be empty, as there are millions that add an explanation. -- With that way of thinking, you could walk pass a sign saying, "No photographing is allowed" with a camera and take pictures, and when caught simply say "I don't understand English" and get away with that.

Comment: I think my quality standards, and my associated enforcement of them, speak for themselves throughout my history on this site. I also have serious issues with the way Stack Overflow the company has conducted themselves over the past 6-8 months, including but not limited to policy changes and abysmal community relations. I fear for where the site is going. Yet, I don't think code-only answers should be flagged, and [I never have](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358757). Don't use this as a barometer to measure the decline of Stack Overflow.

Comment: As for your question of whether a user who has a pattern of posting code-only answers should be allowed to continue doing so, well...that's kind of up to you. Accumulated downvotes are an excellent way of stopping a user from continuing to post answers, and the community holds that power. It also naturally balances out with upvotes: if there are community members who find that user's answers useful and helpful, then they will get enough upvotes to offset the downvotes, and thus retain the privilege to post. There are times when code-only answers are useful; certainly more useful than nothing.