# Should we add "Requires explanation" button to Low quality post review?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, review-queues, low-quality-posts

I saw a lot of code-only posts like this:

> [image: review screen-shot]

I suggest to add "Requires explanation" button to the review. The responsibility of this button is: Adding a comment like [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers):

> While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this should not exist. Leaving a comment is useless. It doesn't solve any of the problems with the post. The goal of this review queue is to *solve the problem*, not kick the can down the road. Once a post completes review, it's pretty much permanently enshrined on the site. We don't want to risk leaving poor-quality posts in that permanent state.

If, while reviewing, you come across an answer that requires explanation, you need to decide: **Can I edit this post to expand it, adding in whatever explanation is required?** This is something you might be able to do as a subject-matter expert, or something that you might just be able to do by reading and understanding the crumbs already present in the answer itself.

Either way, the answer to that question will determine your next course of action:

- If unsure, "Skip".
- If you can edit it, "Edit".
- If you cannot edit it, and you're pretty sure that nobody else but the original answerer is going to be able to edit it, "Recommend Deletion".

Comment: If the reviewer happens to be a subject-matter expert, it's great if they can edit the post to elaborate, but they *usually* aren't (and the system doesn't expect them to be). In the case of code-only answers that would benefit from explanation, as long as the post isn't NAA, the only alternative for a non-expert is to press "Looks OK" (don't delete), because possible solutions without explanation aren't delete-worthy. IMO a comment of "Could you elaborate?" (plus Looks OK) is better than *only* Looks OK. This strategy is already [somewhat common](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256402).

Comment: [Strongly related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358757)

Comment: @Certain Obviously, one should not recommend deletion of an answer that has some redeeming value. I suggest in that other answer that if you think an answer is incomplete, yet cannot improve it yourself, that this would translate to a “Skip” decision in the review queue. “Looks OK” would also be reasonable, if it does. But I am very strongly opposed to enshrining “Leave Comment” as a review action, certainly not one suggested by the UI, as that does not actually solve any problems, and thus defeats the whole purpose of reviewing in the first place.